# nginx proxy, in kubernetes, to multiple docker services

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy

I've a busy service running in a K8 cluster, where all my user-pods have been running on port `1234`:

`docker run 1234:1234 foo`

This has allowed me to have an nginx config of:

```
location ~ /user/([a-z0-9]+) {
    << lots of stuff cut >>
    proxy_pass http://foo-$1.${POD_NAMESPACE}.svc.cluster.local:1234;
    proxy_set_header Host foo-$1:1234;
  }
```

My problem is now that I've a need to include user-pods that expose ports `2345` or `6789`.

I'm happy to spawn the pods to map exposed back to `1234`....

`docker run 1234:6789 foo2`

My question (my lack of understanding) is about nginx: what do the ports in the proxy config refer to: are they talking directly to the exposed port docker image (eg `6789`, `1234`) or the mapped port (`1234` in all cases)?